# How do I say "I am the best" ? の,は or が and 私 or 俺?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-の, particle-が, particle-は

I'm making a shirt for a (rather egotistical) friend of mine and so am trying to do something with the slogan "I am the best" for fun. I need something with four characters only, and would like to ask the difference between

> 私の一番, 
>   私が一番, 
>   私は一番,

and which one would be the most appropriate in the context that he is saying it of himself. My grammar is not fantastic. I understand that が would entail a meaning like "I am the number one" versus は which would be "I am a number one" (correct me if I'm wrong). One of my friends has suggested

> 俺が一番, 
>   俺様一番

Can someone explain to me how 俺 and 私 differ then? I'm quite confused. Also, this is for a boy, just in case anyone wonders.

Comment: 俺 is more 'masculine' and is generally used with males
私 is gender neutral i believe but usually not used by males

Comment: 俺 is less formal and can be used with friends. 私 is used in formal situations pronounced as わたくし, and can be used by both genders. **NEVER** use "俺様", as it is very rude.

Comment: @Flaw what is the proper way to phrase it then if I just want to express "I am the best" or something like "I am better than all of you."?

Comment: @Flaw: what in the world makes you think that?? [一番 can perfectly well be used without an adjective](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22%E3%81%8C%E4%B8%80%E7%95%AA%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: I think you should specify how much comical/jokish or serious and how much impact you want. It all depends on that.

Comment: @fefe: Isn't that the point?  I think "俺様" fits perfectly here for such a blatantly self-aggrandizing message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you correctly note, the `が` in this context adds focus to the noun phrase:

> 私が一番
> '**I** am the best.' or 'The best one is **me**'
>
> 私は一番
> 'I am the **best**.'

`[私]{わたくし}` is very formal and polite, and is not usually used other than in business conversations, `[私]{わたし}` is neutral with politeness, `俺` is rough, and `俺様` is self-appraising. Any of them will work with `は` or `が`.

`私の一番` does not make sense. `俺様一番` without the particle `が` really sounds like a funny phrase made up by a non-Japanese speaker, the kind that indeed is often seen printed on T-shirts or tatoos.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the closest to satisfying would probably be:

> 俺が一番

with possible variants:

> 俺が一番ですよ
>   etc.

Keeping in mind that, no matter what, the phrase in question is going to sound silly (at best) and somewhat boastful verging on rude, I think waffling over the propriety of 俺 in this case is rather out of place. 私 would probably be too soft, and 僕: ridiculously out of place.

I don't think a Japanese would use '一番' in such a context. If anything, the kind of person who would say that (whether seriously or in jest) would probably use some manner of English ("俺がナンバーワン" etc.), but I doubt that would really satiate your friend's craving for something weird and foreign to write on a t-shirt.

PS: '俺様' could also be used here, I think. It is more pompous than rude (well: rude, *because* pompous), but once again: calling yourself 'the best' on a t-shirt has already established that quite clearly already.

Comment: @DaveMG: I am not entirely clear on the reason for your comment, but just in case that was not clear enough: I was mainly responding to the comments on the OP above (and their suggestion that some formulations might be too direct/rude/etc). If anything, my answer goes the exact opposite direction of what you seem to be blaming me for...

Comment: Sorry about that. I guess I misinterpreted because in a broader context of this site, because I feel like I often see advice telling people not to say some things under the common rubric of a usually personally held conviction about what is socially acceptable in Japan. So I think that I projected that onto your answer, which distorted my take on it. So... my bad. I'll delete my comment, since I'm just being off base.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using a different word then `一番`. To me, it feels like the thing you are the best *at* is ommitted. If you wanted to use `一番` I'd go with something like `一番かっこいい`　(the coolest).

My suggestion would be to use `最高{さいこう}` or `最良{さいりょう}` instead.

As for `僕` vs `俺` I think it really has to do with the kind of guy your friend is. If he's big and gruff, you can go with `俺` and if he's not, go with `僕`. Personally (without having met him, of course) I'd lean toward `僕` as it's more flexible.

So what I'd suggest would end up being `僕は最高`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'd like to lend my support to this one, I think 最高 is definitely the way to go in terms of semantic meaning.


While I can't really qualify this, I usually think of 一番 as being used with a noun immediately after it, so 私の一番 sounds a little bit "wrong" to my mind.


Given the unashamed braggadocio here, I think 俺 is the only way to go. It rolls off the tongue and carries all the necessary meaning. Using 僕 would be out of the question.


"I'm the greatest!"