# "俺が一番" vs "俺が最高"

Tags: words, nuances

I was reading through " [How do I say "I am the best" ? の,は or が and 私 or 俺?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3899/264) ", and I was wondering what's the difference between "俺が一番" and "俺が最高"?

From what I know, both roughly equates to "I am the best".

However is there any difference in nuance between "俺が一番" and "俺が最高"?

Comment: If it helps any, the kanji `最` means `the most` coupled with any other kanji that has a degree of measure you can get an idea of how it can be used. `最小 = the minimum` `最後 = the final` `最初 = the first` etc. With 一番, by replacing the 一 (1) you can do `三番 = third` `五番 = fifth` and so forth.

Comment: Your recent questions start with a salutation. I think they should be removed to improve readability.

Comment: @sawa Ok noted.

Answer (score 4):

お早うございます、

Since you are saying "I am the best" and that statement alone carries a bit of ego/arrogance/boast of confidence etc. I would think you'd want to use 俺, 私 sounds neutral/formal. And for the particle, you'd use が since you are pointing out that "I" am the best and none other.

For your second question, both mean relatively the same thing. Though, 一番 is more like, the best, the first (in a series of things or events that can be ranked). 最高 takes a meaning of "the most, the highest, the greatest."

So it just depends on what tone you want to set with your statement.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply =D Btw "最" also implies "first" right.. So do you mean that 一番 is like saying you are the first in something whereas 最高 means that you are the *first* in level?

Answer (score 2):

I think that when you use 最高 for a person, it does not mean "best", but means "very good". That is why it is awkward to use が as in 俺が最高. 一番 retains the meaning "best".

Comment: Thanks for the help =) Btw Do you mena that "一番" would be more proud than "最高" ?

Comment: I think sawa's answer means that those two serve different functions and it is hard to compare them on a linear scale.

Comment: As Flaw points out, one is an absolute notion. The other is a relative (comparative) notion.

Comment: @sawa Ok just to make sure I'm not misunderstanding something, the one that seems to be making a comparison is "一番" right?